# Python boto3 - list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, boto3, boto

I'm trying to create a list in python and getting an error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 592, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 524, in main
    output_file = list_instances(aws_account,aws_account_number, interactive)
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 147, in list_instances
    regions = set_regions(aws_account)
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 122, in set_regions
    regions = list((ec2_client.describe_regions()['Regions']['RegionName']))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Using this code:

```
import boto3
def set_regions(aws_account):
    try:
        ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An exception has occurred: {e}")

    regions = []
    all_gov_regions = ['us-gov-east-1', 'us-gov-west-1']
    alz_regions = ['us-east-1', 'us-west-2']

    managed_aws_accounts = ['company-lab', 'company-bill', 'company-stage' ]
    if aws_account in managed_aws_accounts:
        if 'gov' in aws_account and not 'admin' in aws_account:
            regions = all_gov_regions
        else:
            regions = list(ec2_client.describe_regions()['Regions']['RegionName'])
            print(f"Regions type: {type(regions)}\n\nRegions: {regions}")
    else:
        regions = alz_regions
    return regions
```

Previously I had the error in a try block, that's why we weren't seeing much of the error.

I've updated to show the full code and the full error. I've removed the try block on that part of the code to show more of the error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please provide full stack Trace. it is hard to predict problem.

Comment: Please share complete code. What is `ec2_client` variable over here?

Comment: there must be something more to this code? Could you please post that?

Comment: I've updated the OP to show the full error and the full code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the boto3 doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_regions), `describe_regions` returns a dict of the following form

```py
{
    'Regions': [
        {
            'Endpoint': 'string',
            'RegionName': 'string',
            'OptInStatus': 'string'
        },
    ]
}
```

Note that `response['Regions']` is a list, so you need to index into the list before getting the `RegionName`.  I guess you want something like this:

```py
regions = [reg['RegionName'] for reg in ec2_client.describe_regions()['Regions']]
```